# How to obtain a white background for vim (not gvim)?

Tags: 11.04, command-line, vim

I've downloaded a variety of colorschemes for vim, but none of the white background colorschemes that I've tried have worked in vim, only in gvim. I expect this has to do with the color limitations of the terminal.

I don't need 256 colors, but I would like a decent looking white background that gives some syntax highlighting in the regular Ubuntu 11.04 terminal window.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117526/vim-background

The lightest background possible is a light gray.

```
:highlight Normal ctermfg=blue ctermbg=gray
```

Comment: That question pointed out the obvious answer to my problem: change my terminal colors.

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
:highlight Normal ctermfg=blue ctermbg=none
```

to get a white background